Islandic element names derived from Latin with "-ium" ending
Looking at the islandic periodic table it occured to me that all element names that originate from Latin and end in "-ium" are given in Islandic with the ending "-ìn".
Does anyone know why this is so? I mean instead the -ium ending could have been retained as well. My guess would be that there was some older history of converting Latin names like from religous texts in this way. I understand that the "-ìn" just matches the islandic phonetics much better, however I would be interested in details if possible.
The backgound of this question is that I am about providing some element names for a minority language (Cimbrian) and there could be some kind of principle that I just could adopt.
